# file_get_contents HTTP request failed

Tags: php, http-status-code-401, article

I written simple php code to get some url content but it dosn't work
it return this error

> file_get_contents(http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v508/n7496/full/nature13001.html) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized

here is my code. please help me.tnx

```
$content=file_get_contents('http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v508/n7496/full/nature13001.html');
echo $content;
```

Comment: "HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized" Do you what that means? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
Moreover, http wrapper for file_get_contents does not send normal http headers and can be recognized on the server-side...

Comment: read updated comment. if you are able to reach this URL with browser, but file_get_contents gives you that error, then you have to use cURL, for example, to send full set of http headers. BTW, you may get access to the article from the college/university network, but if script runs on some server outside of the campus network it can give this 401 error, too.

Comment: You mean *here is my code*:  `$content=file_get_contents("http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v508/n7496/full/nature13001.html");`

Comment: I just need content of this url same as browser show. for pattern maching and datamining.

Comment: tank you, i also try to use cURL but its not work :(

Comment: My test reveals `Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v508/n7496/full/nature13001.html): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized in...` so I think they may not be letting anyone scrape their site. You can always try an `<iframe>`.

Comment: i really dont want to show in browser. echo here is for test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative to [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

You might want to add this `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");` if you encounter encoding problem.

Comment: tank you, i also try to use cURL but its not work :(

Comment: @saboteur How is that not working ? Can you explain ?

Comment: it's return something like this
‹ÿŒUÛnÛ8}¶ý‡‰_Ò‘•lÒÝ$kHÚb_vƒ¢ÈC€ 45–˜ò"”}
i try to change encoding but nothing happend

Comment: Add this line: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");`

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the page using your browser and with the console open, see that the server does indeed send a 401 even when page is sent and viewable
2. On php, open the url in an alternate way to ignore the error (see http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)
3. You'll also notice that it's gzip-encoded, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php

Happy hacking!